# Exchange Server 2010 adds '2' to distribution group email address

Tags: exchange-2010

I'm trying to add a distribution group to Exchange 2010 with the name 'info'. After completion of the wizard, the name and the alias show 'info', but Exchange changes the email address of this new group to 'info2'. When I try to change the email addresses (SMTP and X400), Exchange 2010 responds with 'This command will clear the PrimarySMTPAddress property because the EmailAddressPolicyEnabled parameter is set to true.  This action isn't allowed".

I assume somewhere the address info' is already used.  I cannot find where that might be -- I've looked in my active directory as well as exchange administration.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer fully depends on your environment which we do not know yet. However your environment still has a info email address and therefore do not allow you to create a new / additional one. Here the email address policy kicks in and detected that as well and creates a info2 address.

To find the original email adress your fist starting point would be to do some troubleshooting via powershell. The best way here would be something like:

```
Get-Recipient info@yourdomain.com
```

or

```
Get-Recipient -Filter {EmailAddresses -like "*info*"}
```

This should help you to find the email address and where it belongs to.

Comment: The first version of Get-Recipient showed me that the info@mydomain.com was reserved as a public folder.